# Doxygen - starting in command line window with a specific codepage

Tags: command-line, doxygen, codepages

I am using Doxygen for is situated in a folder tree (on a Windows 7 Pro PC) where one of the folders has an Umlaut in its name: `D:\Projects\Wörkspaces\Vision\Doxygen.conf`

When I run Doxygen IN the directory using `doxygen Doxygen.conf`, everything works out fine. Idem when using DoxyWizard.

However, when I try and do `doxygen D:\Projects\Wörkspaces\Vision\Doxygen.conf`, doxygen quits with the error:

> error: configuration file D:\Projects\W÷rkspaces\Vision\Doxygen.conf not found!

and issues the usage instructions.

The same error occurs when I try to run doxygen through a Visual Studio project. Any ideas?

Comment: A bit confusing that in the error message the file is called Doxygen.dox and in the text it is called Doxygen.conf. Which version of doxygen are you using (latest version is 1.8.11)

Comment: Hello Tyler, thanks for your reply! Yes, indeed, my bad, I should have used the same name for the config file. It's the same as a matter of fact. And yes again, I'm using the most recent version of doxygen (1.8.11).

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your filepath. The word "Wörkspaces" contains a special character that might not be recognized. As you see in the error message, "W÷rkspaces" is written.

Try to replace with "Workspaces".

Comment: Dear xSkuulz, thanks for your reply. Indeed, I know that there is a special character and that I could simply replace the ö for an o to fix things. However, I or other people may in other occasions depend on using special characters in their path, and doxygen is apparently NOT using the command line windows's codepage to access the path, rather decoding the character wrongly and throwing an error. My guess is that it may be a bug in doxygen or the underlying Qt in certain WIndows configurations (I'm using Win7 Pro) or, more likely, a configuration issue, which is why I'm publishing it here.